# IEEE affiliation blocks

Tags: ieeetran, affiliation

I'm using the IEEE format to write a paper. I have 4 authors from two institutions so I need blocks of affiliations. This is how I want it to look like:

```
Author 1*, Author 2#, Author 3#, Author 4*
Affiliation 1, {1,4}@abc.com
Affiliation 2, {2,3}@def.com
```

Note that the 1st and the 4th are from one institution, and the 2nd and the 3rd from another one.

Everything is centered, of course.

How to do this?

Answer (score 48):

I found the solution. This is how it's done:

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\author{
    \IEEEauthorblockN{Author1\IEEEauthorrefmark{1}, Author2\IEEEauthorrefmark{2}, Author3\IEEEauthorrefmark{2}, Author4\IEEEauthorrefmark{1}}
    \IEEEauthorblockA{\IEEEauthorrefmark{1}Institution1
    \\\{1, 4\}@abc.com}
    \IEEEauthorblockA{\IEEEauthorrefmark{2}Institution2
    \\\{2, 3\}@def.com}
}
\title{A title}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: Strange that you got this to work. In some of the newer templates I'm finding that: `\def\@IEEEauthorblockAstyle{\smallfont\normalsize}` in the cls is causing issues with the maketitle. The work around is to leave out the `\IEEEauthorblockA` for the information you give, and then it works. Otherwise I think a definition for normalsize is required.

Comment: @EamonnKenny The solution here works for me with an up-to-date TeX Live installation.

Comment: I like this compact style but I wonder whether it complies with the latest IEEE conference template guidelines (*conference-latex-template_10-17-19*), which state: *"Names should not be listed in columns nor group [sic] by affiliation."* My interpretation of the style shown here is that this is a grouping by affiliation. However, (a) the explanations regarding the author block are very brief and leave room for interpretation and (b) I have no experience whether this guideline is accepted by the communities using the template or is just a wishful thinking of the template authors.