# IEEE style author block with sig-alternate.cls

Tags: titles, acm

I am finishing up a paper for an ACM conference, and I have six authors.  I would like to use the IEEE author block format, since it saves space, but I am using the sig-alternate.cls file because it is an ACM conference.  Is there an easy way to keep the general formatting of the sig-alterate.cls file but use an IEEE style author block without changing the document type.

Thanks in advance for your help.  There is a similar entry at [IEEE affiliation blocks](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24894/ieee-affiliation-blocks), but it addresses the problem when you can use ieeetrans directly.

Example of what I want:

```
Author 1*, Author 2#, Author 3@, Author 4#, Author 5$, Author 6$
*Affiliation 1  #Affiliation 2  @Affiliation 3  $Affiliation 4
{1}@abc.com     {2,4}@def.com   {3}@ghi.com     {5,6}@jkl.com
```

Sorry for all the incessant edits.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please add an MWE (minimum working example) of what you're trying to achieve. Please also clarify if have a bib entr with six individual authors or six separate entries with one author each.

Comment: You can use the button to include the image, or upload it directly to imgur, and then a user with enough reputation can include it in your question for you.

Comment: I have figured out how to do what I want to do and will post the code shortly along with the image.

Comment: @Alejo Care to share?