# All authors on single line and affiliations below?

Tags: titles

Is there a way to get all authors of a paper on a single line with affiliations right below them?  When I combine authors and affiliations together in the code below, the formatting does not look good (i.e., bunched up).  This makes me suspect that I should be using an external LaTeX package, but I'm not sure if this is the case.  Perhaps I must use the `authblk` package in the code below? I really have no preference for what package to use as long as it looks good:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn, prl]{revtex4}

\makeindex

%--------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}

\title{My title}

\author{Name1}
\email{email1@email.com}
\affiliation{University name\\ Department name\\ Address}

\author{Name2}
\email{email2@email.com}
\affiliation{University name3\\ Department name\\ Address}

\author{Name3}
\email{email3@email.com}
\affiliation{University name2\\ Department name\\ Address}


\begin{abstract}
  The abstract starts here.  Filling space now: etc etc etc...
\end{abstract}


\maketitle

\section{Introduction}

My introduction starts here...

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Why don't you just leave this up to the journal to figure out? Also, why not use `revtex4-1`?

Comment: @Werner What can I say?... I love making LaTeX typesetting myself and wouldn't just give it to them that easy! ;)  In reality though, I need a working pre-submission pdf draft to show my boss.  `revtex4-1` changes my bibliographic and email address configurations.

Comment: Try the class option `superscriptaddress`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hat-tip to username mvkorpel, who suggested that I try class option `superscript address`.  Code below, with `\\` removed:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn, prl, superscriptaddress]{revtex4}

\makeindex

%--------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}

\title{My title}

\author{Name1}
\email{email1@email.com}
\affiliation{University name, Department name, Address}

\author{Name2}
\email{email2@email.com}
\affiliation{University name3, Department name, Address}

\author{Name3}
\email{email3@email.com}
\affiliation{University name2, Department name, Address}


\begin{abstract}
  The abstract starts here.  Filling space now: etc etc etc...
\end{abstract}


\maketitle

\section{Introduction}

My introduction starts here...

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The following answer is credited to Alan Munn at https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/24946.

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\author{
    \IEEEauthorblockN{Author1\IEEEauthorrefmark{1},
                      Author2\IEEEauthorrefmark{2},
                      Author3\IEEEauthorrefmark{2},
                      Author4\IEEEauthorrefmark{1}}

    \IEEEauthorblockA{\IEEEauthorrefmark{1}Institution1
    \\\{1, 4\}@abc.com}

    \IEEEauthorblockA{\IEEEauthorrefmark{2}Institution2
    \\\{2, 3\}@def.com}
}
\title{A title}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```