# IEEE Conferences - Dual Affiliation for One Author

Tags: ieeetran, affiliation

I am just preparing the camera ready for a IEEE conference.

One of the authors (Author 4) started his research on this project at University A and is now based at University C.

Is the following code an acceptable way to show this?
[image]

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,10pt,conference]{IEEEtran}

\IEEEoverridecommandlockouts % Don't forget this command!

\begin{document}

\title{Paper Title}}


\author{\IEEEauthorblockN{Author 1}%
  \IEEEauthorblockA{{University A}
    } \and
  
  \IEEEauthorblockN{Author 2}
  \IEEEauthorblockA{Organisation B} \and
  
  \IEEEauthorblockN{Author 3}
  \IEEEauthorblockA{Organisation B} 
  
  \and
  
  \IEEEauthorblockN{Author 4}
  \IEEEauthorblockA{University A}
  \IEEEauthorblockA{University C}

  \and
   \IEEEauthorblockN{Author 5}
  \IEEEauthorblockA{University A} 
  
}

\maketitle

\section{INTRODUCTION}
Hola

\bibliographystyle{IEEEbib}
\bibliography{IEEEabrv,References}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe the most common way to handle multiple authors from the same institution is the following ([as you can see from this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24894/ieee-affiliation-blocks)):

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,10pt,conference]{IEEEtran}
\IEEEoverridecommandlockouts % Don't forget this command!

\begin{document}
\title{Paper Title}}

\author{
    \IEEEauthorblockN{
        Author 1\IEEEauthorrefmark{1}, Author 2\IEEEauthorrefmark{2}, Author 3\IEEEauthorrefmark{2}, Author 4\IEEEauthorrefmark{1}\IEEEauthorrefmark{3}, Author 5\IEEEauthorrefmark{1}
    }
    \IEEEauthorblockA{\IEEEauthorrefmark{1} University A}
    \IEEEauthorblockA{\IEEEauthorrefmark{2} Organization B}
    \IEEEauthorblockA{\IEEEauthorrefmark{3} Now at University C}
}

\maketitle
\end{document}
```

[image]

The few times I actually saw something resembling what you showed in the question, authors with the same affiliation were clustered:

```
\author{
  \IEEEauthorblockN{Author 1, Author 5}%
  \IEEEauthorblockA{University A} \and
  
  \IEEEauthorblockN{Author 2, Author 3}
  \IEEEauthorblockA{Organisation B} \and  
  
  \IEEEauthorblockN{Author 4}
  \IEEEauthorblockA{University A}
  \IEEEauthorblockA{Now at University C}
}
```

[image]

Of course this would probably lead to a different order of authorship, which is something you may not want.

Comment: Hello Davide. Thanks, I was thinking something like this - https://rud.is/dl/ieee-sp-2018/435301a870.pdf . But instead of clustering authors by affiliation, simply having each author's affiliation individually.

Comment: Then the code you posted works just fine, unless you have many authors with long affiliations that will cause you to run out of space. Whether it is acceptable or not depends on the conference you target, usually IEEE ones provide a template with this kind of information; then it's not a matter of Latex typesetting, only the editor's choice.

Comment: Brilliant, thank you very much for taking the time to answer this, Davide. As it's published at the same conference as the paper I linked, I hope it will be fine. Thanks again.